# Getting "is not a function " errors with RxJS

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx, angular2-observables

Seemingly out of the blue I am getting errors with RxJS.

My project is Angular, Typescript and I use RxJS as part of NGRX redux.

My code *seemed* to work absolutely fine with just this as an import:

`import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'`

Then, from nowhere I started getting errors like this...

`Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.appStateStore.withLatestFrom is not a function`
`Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.appStateStore.take is not a function`

I was able to solve the error about `withLatestFrom` by adding an import of `import 'rxjs/add/operator/withLatestFrom';` but then the error moved to complaining about `.take`.

I'm guessing I have an import wrong somewhere as I understand with RxJS you need to import the bits that you need. However I've reviewed my source control changes and I can't see that any changes (e.g. node module version, import statements) that would cause this to just start happening.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Then add `import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged'; import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged'; 
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take;
```

**Rxjs v 5.4.1**

### 1) `import { Rx } from 'rxjs/Rx`;

This imports the entire library. Then you don't need to worry about loading each operator . But you need to append Rx. <s>I hope tree-shaking will optimize and pick only needed funcionts( need to verify )</s> As mentioned in comments , tree-shaking can not help. So this is not optimized way.

```
public cache = new Rx.BehaviorSubject('');
```

---

Or you can import **individual** operators .

**This will Optimize your app to use only those files** :

### 2) `import { _______ } from 'rxjs/_________';`

This syntax usually used for main Object like `Rx` itself or `Observable` etc.,

Keywords which can be imported with this syntax

```
 Observable, Observer, BehaviorSubject, Subject, ReplaySubject
```

### 3) `import 'rxjs/add/observable/__________';`

These are usually accompanied with Observable directly. For example

```
Observable.from()
Observable.of()
```

Other such keywords which can be imported using this syntax:

```
concat, defer, empty, forkJoin, from, fromPromise, if, interval, merge, of, 
range, throw, timer, using, zip
```

### 4) `import 'rxjs/add/operator/_________';`

These usually come in the stream after the Observable is created. Like `flatMap` in this code snippet:

```
Observable.of([1,2,3,4])
          .flatMap(arr => Observable.from(arr));
```

Other such keywords using this syntax:

```
audit, buffer, catch, combineAll, combineLatest, concat, count, debounce, delay, 
distinct, do, every, expand, filter, finally, find , first, groupBy,
ignoreElements, isEmpty, last, let, map, max, merge, mergeMap, min, pluck, 
publish, race, reduce, repeat, scan, skip, startWith, switch, switchMap, take, 
takeUntil, throttle, timeout, toArray, toPromise, withLatestFrom, zip
```

**FlatMap**: 
`flatMap` is alias to `mergeMap` so we need to import `mergeMap` to use `flatMap`.

---

**Note for `/add` imports** :

We only need to import once in whole project. So its advised to do it at a single place. If they are included in multiple files, and one of them is deleted, the build will fail for wrong reasons.